# Problems connecting to Postgres from Grails

Tags: postgresql, grails

I have verified that I can connect to the postgres database using a Java test program. I have also verified that I can connect using a little Grails testDB project. But when I try to run my larger project, which the same BuildConfig.groovy, it fails.

I've tried different jdbc versions (e.g., 4 rather than 41) in the postgres jar, but it didn't help.

I've been searching stackoverflow and anything else I can find to no avail (e.g., "help me stackoverflow, your my only hope").

My BuildConfig.groovy file is shown below:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]


grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.2.1"
        // compile ":jquery-dialog:2.0.3"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ":twitter-bootstrap:3.2.1"

    }
}
```

My DataSource.groovy file contains

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://150.18.178.9:5432/myDB"
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dbCreate = "update"
    username = "user"
    password = "password"
    dialect = net.sf.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource { // database dev
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url="jdbc:postgresql://150.18.178.9:5432/dev"
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource { 
            dbCreate = "update"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://150.18.178.9:5432/test"
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://150.18.178.9:5432/myDB"
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run my application I get:

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Dgrails.home=/home/iank/software/grails/latest -Dbase.dir=/home/iank/IdeaProjects/nderground -Dtools.jar=/usr/java/latest/lib/tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/home/iank/software/grails/latest/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -javaagent:/home/iank/software/grails/latest/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Didea.launcher.port=7535 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/iank/software/idea-IU-135.909/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/iank/software/grails/latest/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.3.6.jar:/home/iank/software/grails/latest/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.4.3.jar:/home/iank/software/idea-IU-135.909/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /home/iank/software/grails/latest/conf/groovy-starter.conf "run-app -plain-output"
|Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
...........
|Compiling 1 source files
............................
|Running Grails application
| Error 2014-09-27 17:16:38,021 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
->>   22 | doCall    in nderground.User$__clinit__closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/nderground

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated. My progress has completely stalled and I'm not sure what to do other than to try rebuilding the project piece by piece.

Many thanks...

Comment: Did you clean the project first? I mean: use the grails clean command and then grails run-app.

Comment: Can you try removing postgres dependencies from buildconfig and add the postgres jdbc jar in the grails-app/lib folder.

Comment: Why do you think you have a problem connecting to postgresql? Nothing in your log points to a connection problem with postgres. However it does say: `Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory'`

Answer (score 1):

By creating a Grails project that worked and slowly adding code I was able to find the problem. I had an improperly specified constraint.

```html
class User {
 String handle
    String emailAddr
 String salt
 String password
    boolean isAdmin
    
    String toString()
    {
        String rslt = "$handle"
        return rslt 
    }

    static constraints = {
        handle blank : false, nullable : false, unique : true
        emailAddr blank : false, nullable : false, unique : true, email : true
  salt blank: false, nullable: false
  password blank: false, nullable: false
  isAdmin false  <<======= This is the problem!
    }
    
    static mapping = {
        table 'users'
        handle index : 'handle_Ix'
        emailAddr index: 'email_ix'
  isAdmin defaultValue: false
    }
}
```

This should have been in the static mapping section:

```html
static mapping = {
        table 'users'
        handle index : 'handle_Ix'
        emailAddr index: 'email_ix'
  isAdmin defaultValue: false  <<== This is the right way to set the default
    }
```

To put it mildly, its annoying that the error shows up as a thread creation error, without any other indication of other errors.

Answer (score 0):

As @EElke points out in the comments, there's no indication at all that Postgres is the problem; the error that you should be looking at says `Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' ... object is not an instance of declaring class`.

My guess is that `net.sf.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` is the problem - replace that with `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`.

Also, delete this:

```
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
```

since you already have

```
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
```

and runtime scope includes dependencies from compile scope.